# Light Out Puzzle Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms

I am decided to solve the puzzle game named [Lights out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out). So, i choose linear-algebra to solve my problem, so note that [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle.html) link, i start my work as follow :

*NOTE : Any light states can accept two values, on = 1 and off = 0, {0,1} and all calculation will be done in this set.*

1. The summation operator used in theorem is : 1 + 1 = 0 + 0 = 0 and 1 + 0 = 0 + 1 = 1
2. The multiplication operator used in theorem is : 1 *  1 = 1 and else are 0.
3. For each action v, we can prove that v + v = 0 (using summation operator)

   - v is the 5x5 matrix shows the light status.
4. Each button should be pressed at once. ( v + v = 0 )
5. All of computing can be done in modulo 2. (on and off)
6. Suppose matrix `Act_i` which pressing `i`'th button in Zero-Matrix, converts this matrix to `Act_i`. For example Act_10, converts Zero-Matrix (5x5) to :

> ```
> 0 0 0 0 1
> 0 0 0 1 1
> 0 0 0 0 1
> 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0
> ```

1. I show the initial state of puzzle table (5x5) in row-matrix. (25x1)

   - Row matrix `B` = (b1, b2, b3, ..., b25)
2. Suppose that matrix `X` is the matrix that we should pressed to convert matrix `B`to Zero matrix. (the goal of problem)
3. Suppose Matrix `A` that is 25x25 matrix and i'th row of this matrix equals to `Act_i` (look at 6)

Finally, i have the equation *`AX = B`* that we can solve it easily. I tried to solve this using the matrix library in `Java`. But, this work wrong to solve the solution.

Example:

A =

> ```
> 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
> 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
> 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
> 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0
> 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
> 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1
> 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
> 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1
> 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
> ```

B =

> ```
> 0
> 1
> 0
> 1
> 1
> 0
> 0
> 1
> 1
> ```

But, my computational X is equals to  :
X =

> ```
>  1.285714
> -0.142857
> -0.714286
> -1.142857
>  0.571429
>  0.857143
>  0.285714
>  0.857143
> -0.714286
> ```

But it is wrong, because of this [solution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle.html).

Answer X =

> ```
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 1
> ```

Could any one tell me what thing is wrong ? Why my calculation answer is wrong ?!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: We can't say. You have a given $A$ and $b$, and you are supposed to solve for $x$ so that $Ax = b$. The system is set up correctly, but we don't know how you actually computed it. So we can't fix your computation.

Comment: Presumably Java's matrix library is set up to do matrix computations over $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$. The lights-out puzzle forms a vector space over $\Bbb{Z}/2$. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916493/solving-equation-systems-over-finite-fields has some links to libraries that'll do what you want; one in C++ and one in Java (though they might be more high-powered than you need).

Comment: Results like 1.285714 doesn't sound like you're doing the computation modulo 2, such as you decided to.

Comment: @Micah: thanks for your comment and link :)

Comment: @HenningMakholm is right.  A fix might be to multiply the result by the determinant (which in this case is $\pm 7$, i didn't check which) and then take everything mod $2$.  You'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Thank for your note :)

Comment: @Cocopuffs: i try to solve this problem. Thanks :)